# Actionscript 3 perform an action if the user has not interacted with the animation

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation

Is there an easy way for an action to occur if the user has taken no action in say 30 seconds? No action means no clicking, and no scrolling but if the user moves their mouse this should not count as an action.

My animation is for a website and I want it to be able to display an animation loop if the user is not actively interacting with the interactive portion of the animation.

Comment: You could add a timer and listeners for all mouse events (down, up) and keyboard events (key down, key up) to your stage (or movieclip) and check if none of them has occured after 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new [`Timer`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html) and set it's `delay` to 30 seconds.
2. When the `TimerEvent` fires, start the animation loop.
3. When any action occurs that should be considered an interaction of the user, call [`reset()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html#reset%28%29) and [`start()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html#start%28%29) on the `Timer` object to rewind it.

Alternatively, according to the documentation, you should be able to restart the `Timer` object by assigning a value to the [`.delay`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html#delay) property:

> If you set the delay interval while the timer is running, the timer will restart at the same `repeatCount` iteration.

As you'd be setting the same value for the delay again (30 seconds) I'm not sure if this would also work.